# Can I store a maven command in the pom?

Tags: maven, maven-3

Sometimes I need to run custom maven commands, e.g:

```
mvn install -DskipTests -DfailIfNoTests=false
```

I would like to be able to save this command so I don't have to type it out every time, e.g.

```
mvn forceInstall
```

Of course I can create run configurations in my IDE but I'm wondering if this is possible using maven only.

Comment: I think that's what profiles are for.

Comment: Create a profile and add the two options to Surefire configuration. Then you  can call your command with `mvn install -P myProfile`

Comment: Profile are the way to go. If the command require something else than maven (famous ```rm -rf /``` for example :)), you could use maven-exec-plugin too, and put whatever command you need in it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name not really take a look into my answer...

Answer (score 0):

In the `pom.xml` you can define a [default goal like this](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#BaseBuild_Element):

```xml
<project>
  <build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    ...
  </build>
</project>
```

so you can use simply `mvn` only instead of `mvn install`. But for your need it would be better to use the [`.mvn/maven.config`](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/release-notes.html) file which will be part of your project which can contain any kind of Maven commands. So you create a file in `.mvn/maven.config` which contains:

```
-DskipTests
-DfailIfNoTests=false
```

This can be used starting with Maven 3.3.1+.
Apart from that I would really reconsider using `-DskipTests` as default which from my experience only makes occasionally sense. What makes often sense is to use things like `-T 4` etc. in the `.mvn/maven.config` file...or `--fail-at-end`. Be careful that those options file is not taken into account by CI server like Jenkins etc.